# I want to open a particular page of my app on notification click.(Ionic2)

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

Consider this scenario. I have an ionic2 app and I am using the the FCM plugin for push notifications. Now let us say a push notification arrives when the app is in the background. User, views the notification in the App drawer and then clicks the notification for further information. I would like the user to navigate to a particular path using this.nav.push(PushPage). How can I tap into the notification click event?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform,NavController,AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';


import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import {PushPage} from '../pages/push/push';
declare var FCMPlugin;
@Component({
templateUrl: 'app.html',
providers :[FCM]

})
export class MyApp {
 rootPage:any = HomePage;
 @ViewChild(NavController) nav;

constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: 
 SplashScreen,private fcm: FCM,
 private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
   platform.ready().then(() => {
   statusBar.styleDefault();
   splashScreen.hide();

   fcm.subscribeToTopic('marketing');
   fcm.getToken().then(token=>{

  })

   fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data=>{
    if(data.wasTapped){
     console.log("Received in background");
     this.nav.push(PushPage); 
   } else {
       console.log("Received in foreground");
       this.nav.push(PushPage);
   };
 })

  fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token=>{
    this.nav.push(PushPage);
 })
  fcm.unsubscribeFromTopic('marketing');

   });

 }

}
```

Comment: I solved my problem.I have studied and applied the example here https://github.com/aggarwalankush/ionic2-push-base